# How to draw the 5 dimensional hypercube graph with 56 edge crossings?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I'm probably doing something stupid but I can't seem to think of a way to draw $Q_5$ with $cr(Q_5) = 56 $. In this [paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0898122188902131) the author says drawing a hypercube graph with $\leq56$ edge crossings is easy (look under section 3 topological invariants) Could anyone give me an idea of how to get 56 edge crossings. I always end up getting 60 when I draw it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the article where this fact is shown.  However, I can't access it in it's entirety without paying... [Here it is](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/jgt.3190150109/pdf) It shows the first page, but everything else is kind of blurred out.  It does not have the same layout as Ed Pegg's answer.  I will try and edit this with a picture of the graph, but in the meantime, if maybe you have access to the above article, you can see it for yourself.

EDIT:  Here is a drawing of $Q_5$ with 56 crossings.  I believe it is still conjectured that $cr(Q_5)=56$
[image: 999999999999999999999]

Answer (score 4):

Here's a cleaner version of the 56 crossing.  The left and right wrap around.

[image: Hypercube 5]

Comment: Nice one!  What are you using to make your figures, if you don't mind?

Comment: I use Mathematica, Autocad, and Illustrator. Fairly heavy duty.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running into 60 as well.  I'd also like to see the 56.

[image: 5-hypercube]

Comment: Yes it is pretty odd. I have been researching hypercube crossing numbers recently and a lot of papers reference that Q5 <= 56 has been shown already and they cite the paper I linked which doesn't actually draw it with 56.